# Custom Helper in CakePHP Error

Tags: cakephp, helper, cakephp-2.1, view-helpers

Fairly experienced programmer but new to CakePHP 2.1 and spending my day struggling to get a custom Helper to work in View by following the manual: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/helpers.html

I've not been able to find an answer and would greatly appreciate any Cake expertise.

My helper file in app/Helper/EntriesHelper.php:

```
App::uses('AppHelper', 'View/Helper');

class EntriesHelper extends AppHelper {

    public function __construct(View $view, $settings = array()) {
        parent::__construct($view, $settings);
    }

    public function spanWrapper($content) {

        if(substr($content,0,1) == "@") {
            return "<span class='label label-warning'>$content</span>";
        }
        else if(substr($content,0,1) == "#") {
            return "<span class='label label-default'>$content</span>";
        } 
        else if (substr($content,0,4) == "http" || substr($content,0,3) == "www") {
            return "<span class='label'>$content</span>";
        }

        return $content;

    }

}
```

And my controller in app/Controller/EntriesController:

```
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');

class EntriesController extends AppController {

    public $helpers = array('Form', 'Html', 'Js', 'Time');

    #public $components = array('RequestHandler');

    #public $viewClass = 'Json';

    public function index() {

        $helpers[] = 'spanWrapper';
        $this->Entry->recursive = 1;
        $this->set('entries', $this->paginate());
        #$this->set('_serialize', array('entries'));

    }
}
```

But a call from my View fails:

```
$this->Entries->spanWrapper($entry['Entry']['title']);
```

With the error:

```
Notice (8): Undefined property: View::$Entries [CORE/Cake/View/View.php, line 806]
Fatal error: Call to a member function spanWrapper() on a non-object in <path removed>/app/View/Entries/index.ctp on line 35
```

So the notice of undefined property is presumably causing the fatal error ... but why so, if it's implemented per the cookbook?

Darren

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct syntax is `$this->helpers[] = 'spanWrapper';` when loading a helper within a method, or add it to your public `$helpers` array instead.

Comment: besides the fact that it should best be "SpanWrapper" to stay consistent (CamelCase)

Comment: Ah. I see. <ahem> thanks .... that worked. I think I had used the example in the cookbook , I'll check and see if their code is perhaps wrong too.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use your helper in the entire controller, you should add it to the `$helpers` array in your `EntriesController`:

```
class EntriesController extends AppController {

  public $helpers = array('Form', 'Html', 'Js', 'Time', 'Entries');

  /* ... */

}
```

If you need the helper in your entire application, you can add it to the `AppController` the same way.

If on the other side you only need it in one single view, you may choose to only load it there dynamically. In your view, call [`HelperCollection->view()`](http://api20.cakephp.org/class/helper-collection#method-HelperCollectionload) just before you want to use the helper for the first time:

```
$this->Helpers->load('Entries');
```

All three methods are [documented very well](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/helpers.html) in the CakePHP book.

Comment: or just upgrade to 2.2 - then the helper should be lazy loaded automatically :)